MUI TreeView package Error of querySelectorAll
I am using mui latest version and latest version of treeview package in my web application
this is sample code on MUI website as sample of use (i have used the same for testing)
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { SimpleTreeView } from '@mui/x-tree-view/SimpleTreeView';
import { TreeItem } from '@mui/x-tree-view/TreeItem';

export default function BasicSimpleTreeView() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ minHeight: 352, minWidth: 250 }}>
      <SimpleTreeView>
        <TreeItem itemId="grid" label="Data Grid">
          <TreeItem itemId="grid-community" label="@mui/x-data-grid" />
          <TreeItem itemId="grid-pro" label="@mui/x-data-grid-pro" />
          <TreeItem itemId="grid-premium" label="@mui/x-data-grid-premium" />
        </TreeItem>
        <TreeItem itemId="pickers" label="Date and Time Pickers">
          <TreeItem itemId="pickers-community" label="@mui/x-date-pickers" />
          <TreeItem itemId="pickers-pro" label="@mui/x-date-pickers-pro" />
        </TreeItem>
        <TreeItem itemId="charts" label="Charts">
          <TreeItem itemId="charts-community" label="@mui/x-charts" />
        </TreeItem>
        <TreeItem itemId="tree-view" label="Tree View">
          <TreeItem itemId="tree-view-community" label="@mui/x-tree-view" />
        </TreeItem>
      </SimpleTreeView>
    </Box>
  );
}


it is throwing following error
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Element': '[role="treeitem"]:not(*[id=":r2f:"] [role="treeitem"] [role="treeitem"])' is not a valid selector
i have not used any css changes like above ----- how to get this resolved
i have tried to change the itemId to nodeId in treeItem but still the same error in both development and production mode.
